# Nestjs how to properly map 2 tables with a middle table

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using `Postgres` as database have the next tables:

**Students**

```
id: Integer (PK)
name: Text
```

**Subject**

```
id: Integer (PK)
name: Text
```

**student_assignation**

```
student_id: Integer (PK)
subject_id: Integer (PK)
```

Those tables haven't an `Auto-generated PK`.
So, my entities are:

**Student.entity.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { student_assignation } from './student_assignation.entity';
import { Subject } from './subject.entity';

@Entity()
export class Student {
  @Column('number')
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('text')
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => student_assignation, x => x.subject_id)
  //student_assignations: student_assignation[];
}
```

Well, here is my question:
I'm trying to get all the subjects assigned to a user.
In `SQL` terms, I would define it like:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, u.name, r.id, r.name
FROM  
    student u INNER JOIN student_assignation ra
        ON u.id = ra.student_id
    INNER JOIN subject r
        ON r.id = ra.subject_id
WHERE
    u.id = 1
```

But at the moment to convert and use it in nestjs, I have this relation:

```
@OneToMany(type => student_assignation, x => x.subject_id)

@ManyToOne(type => subject, x => x.id)
```

But, is not retrieving any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need many-to-many relation. Take a look on TypeOrm implementation [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your entities in `many-to-many` relation:

```js
@Entity()
export class Student {
    @Column('number')
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column('text')
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Subject)
    @JoinTable({ name: 'student_assignation' })
    subjects: Subject[];
}


@Entity()
export class Subject {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Student)
    students: Student[];
}
```

To retrieve a user with all subjects:

```js
const user = await User.findOne(USER_ID, { relations: ['subjects'] })
console.log(user.subjects);
```